# The cow of the Tzadik from Strelisk

Tags: story-identification, allegory-mashal, hasidic-story

When I was young, I read the following story / parable:

> Every evening, the Tzadik of Strelisk comes home after the evening prayer and feeds his cow. Every evening in the same hour.
>
> One evening, the Tzadik got very excited during the prayer. He wept so much about the sorrow of the Shechina, that he forgot the time and did not come home in time.
>
> During this time, the cow thought to herself: "why does my master not give me the food? What happened? I know! He must have taken the food to himself! He liked my food! Poor me! My master is surely dining and feasting on my food and leaves me hungry!...

This message of this parable is that, when we try to understand the actions of Tzadikim in the past (especially in Biblical times), we  often behave like this cow - we interpret their actions according to our very material conceptions.

I read this parable in an old book. Now, I do not find its source anywhere. Can anyone find the source of this story?